# Class "GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack" not found in (laravel) Pest-Test

Tags: laravel, guzzle, php-pest

i want to test an api-client. the api-client uses Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http to make requests. when i use it in tinker everything is ok:

```
> $response = Bitwarden::listItems()
= Illuminate\Support\Collection {#6782
    all: [
      {#6854
        +"object": "item",
       ....
      },
    ],
  }
```

My test looks like this:

```
it('can list the items', function () {
   $response = Bitwarden::listItems();
   expect($response)->toBeArray();
});
```

and result is

```
 FAILED  Tests\BitwardenCliTest > it can list the items                              Error   
  Class "GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack" not found

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php:1145
    1141▕      * @return \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack
    1142▕      */
    1143▕     public function buildHandlerStack()
    1144▕     {
  ➜ 1145▕         return $this->pushHandlers(HandlerStack::create($this->handler));
    1146▕     }
    1147▕ 
    1148▕     /**
    1149▕      * Add the necessary handlers to the given handler stack.
```

i guess i missed something in setting up pest. please give me a hint. thx :)

i want the client to work in test like it does in tinker

Comment: Please share more details. The code you've shared does not contain any calls to Guzzle

Answer (score 0):

since i'm using jetstream in this project, i "reinstalled" it using pest as testing-framework like mentioned here [https://jetstream.laravel.com/installation.html#:~:text=If%20you%20would%20like%20to%20use%20Pest%20PHP%20for%20testing%2C%20you%20may%20use%20the%20%2D%2Dpest%20switch%20to%20install%20a%20Pest%20test%20suite%20instead%20of%20the%20default%20PHPUnit%20test%20suite](https://jetstream.laravel.com/installation.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20would%20like%20to%20use%20Pest%20PHP%20for%20testing%2C%20you%20may%20use%20the%20%2D%2Dpest%20switch%20to%20install%20a%20Pest%20test%20suite%20instead%20of%20the%20default%20PHPUnit%20test%20suite).

now my tests are passing!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).